# Python Storing Images in List Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to store every jpg image in a list. I have more than 1,000 images. Before I store an image in my list, I can display it. However, once it is inside my list, I cannot display it. It seems like the image is closed before it gets into the list even though I close the image after I store it in my list. Please help.

```
image_list = []   # list for train images
filename = 'data/training_images/'  # file that has train images
for filename in glob.glob('data/training_images/*.jpg'):  # grab all the images
    im=Image.open(filename)
    # plt.imshow(im)   --> works
    image_list.append(im) 
    # plt.imshow(image_list[0])   --> works
    im.close()  # I need it because I have many images
    plt.imshow(image_list[0])  # --> error; does not work
```

> TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Answer (score 1):

The data you are putting into your list is the result of the `open` function. The returned value from that function is not the contents of the file but rather a file handle. In CPython I believe that handle is just an integer. That handle tells Python and the operating system where to find the file, as long as the file remains open. When you close the file, the handle becomes meaningless.

You need to get the *contents* of each file into a Python data type after you open the file, and store *that* into your list. Perhaps use the `read` function to get the data into a `bytes` structure.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Image.open()

> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the file remains open and the actual image data is not read from the file until you try to process the data

This function returns an Image object. Once you call **im.close()**, it closes the file pointer and hence the image is not accessible.

We can use cv2 or matplotlib to read the images and store it in the list.

```
 im = cv2.imread(filename) 
 # im will be a numpy array 
 image_list.append(im)
```